# Calling a flow that creates a list of uploaded files from an apex class is always one file behind

Tags: apex, trigger, visual-workflow, files, contentdocumentlink

I am using a Flow to update a File_links__c on a record with the list of all the files for that record. This flow was originally a record-triggered flow. Editing any field in the record triggers a File_links__c update and it's able to get all the files, even the latest one.

This flow is called from ContentDocumentLinkTriggerHandler class. I'm trying to use as little code as possible (client constraints).

The flow is supposed to run whenever a file is uploaded/deleted from a record, but it's always 1 file behind. I guess due to File upload being async?

ContentDocumentLinkTrigger

```
trigger ContentDocumentLinkTrigger on ContentDocumentLink (before insert) {
    System.debug('Called!');
    
   if(Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isInsert){
        ContentDocumentLinkTriggerHandler.onBeforeInsert(Trigger.new);
   }
   
}
```

ContentDocumentLinkTriggerHandler:

```
public with sharing class ContentDocumentLinkTriggerHandler{
    public class ContentDocumentLinkTriggerHandlerException extends Exception {}
    
    
    public static void solicitationFile(Id solicitationId){
        System.debug('in solicitation file');
        List<FundingOpportunity> parentCase = [SELECT Id, Status,File_uploaded__c, Description FROM FundingOpportunity WHERE ID =: solicitationId];
        List<FundingOpportunity> updatedSol = new List<FundingOpportunity>();
        Map<string, Object> params = new Map<String, Object>();
        for(FundingOpportunity c: parentCase){                
            
            if (c.Status == 'Closed' || c.Status == 'Canceled' || c.Status == 'Cancelled'){
                System.debug('Cant upload files because Soliciation is ' + c.Status);
                throw new ContentDocumentLinkTriggerHandlerException('You cant upload file because Solicitation is ' + c.Status);                      
            }
         
            //IdFromApex is the variable used in the flow
            params.put('IdFromApex', c.Id);

            
        }
        system.debug('Uploaded file!');

        //Flow is called here
        Flow.Interview.Autolaunched_Solicitation_Update_Files_field fileLinks = new Flow.Interview.Autolaunched_Solicitation_Update_Files_field(params);
        fileLinks.start();
    }
   
    public static void onBeforeInsert(List<ContentDocumentLink> cdls){
        
        Boolean hasPermission = FeatureManagement.checkPermission('Solicitation_Edit');
        System.debug('Solicitation Read: ' +  hasPermission);
        
        Boolean granMan = FeatureManagement.checkPermission('GrantmakingManager');
        System.debug('granMan ' + granMan);
        
        Boolean grantSet = FeatureManagement.checkPermission('Grant_Making_Set');
        System.debug('grantSet ' + grantSet);
        
        if(hasPermission == True || granMan == True){
            throw new ContentDocumentLinkTriggerHandlerException('You are not allowed to upload Files');      
        }
        for (ContentDocumentLink cdl : cdls) {
            
            String programPref = String.valueOf(Program.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getKeyPrefix());
            String fundingOppPref = String.valueOf(FundingOpportunity.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getKeyPrefix());
            String relatedDocPref = String.valueOf(cdl.LinkedEntityId.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getKeyPrefix());   
            
           if(relatedDocPref == fundingOppPref){
                solicitationFile(cdl.LinkedEntityId);
            }
            else{
                System.debug('Upload is allowed');
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: this should be an after insert trigger